# Let default value for parameter take precedence if test fails

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is just a curiosity question for a "good" pythonic way to do this.

I have a function with an optional parameter ie.

```
def foo( a, b, c='en' ):
    print c
```

There is a dict with a bunch of info in it, and if a particular key is in the dict, I would like to pass it into foo to override c's default, but if the key is not in the dict, I just want to use the default for c.

Obviously this will work...

```
if "SomeKey" in mydict:
    foo( val1, val2, mydict[ "SomeKey" ]
else:
    foo( val1, val2 )
```

And another option would be to do something like

```
params = [ val1, val2 ]
if "SomeKey" in mydict:
    params.append( mydict[ "SomeKey" ] )
foo( *params )
```

but there must be a slick, more pythonic way to do this?  ie.

```
foo( val1, val2, mydict[ "SomeKey" ] if "SomeKey" in mydict else < use default > )
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a "true" default value for this - instead, use a placeholder value:

```
def foo( a, b, c=None ):
    if c is None:
        c = 'en'
    print c
```

and then just call with...

```
foo( val1, val2, mydict.get("SomeKey") )
```

(`.get()` returns `None` if the key isn't in the dict, by default)

---

If you can't modify `foo()`, then you can do the more complex varargs path:

```
maybe_c = {'c': mydict["SomeKey"]} if "SomeKey" in mydict else {}
foo( val1, val2, **maybe_c )
```

Comment: +1. Like the second way, even more than the first :) Would have given +2 if allowed.

Comment: The 2nd way is pretty neat!  Not that the first way doesn't work nicely as well :)  good answers!

Comment: I actually prefer the "runtime default" (first) approach for this -- I see that all the time in the Python standard libraries, and I think it's the most idiomatic approach.

Comment: The first approach explicitly prevents you from passing `None` to your function though.  While that's usually not a problem, occasionally it is from an API standpoint.

Comment: ya even though the 2nd way is a neat way to use ** unpacking, I went with the first way - readability counts :)

Comment: @mgilson, that's a good point. One way around that might be to use a custom default sentinel object, though I'd only do that if the problem actually presented itself.

Comment: @senderle -- I think the original version of this answer did have a custom sentinel.  That's a neat trick, but then if you want to say "give me the default", you need to remember how to get a handle on the sentinel.  Personally, I prefer to avoid that madness when getting the default parameter is as easy as calling the function without that keyword (and specifying a reasonable default in the function definition)

Comment: Yeah, using a custom sentinel can work if you need to have `None` as an option to actually pass in, but requires slightly more complexity. (Another fun trick is storing the default sentinel value as a property on the function object - e.g. `foo(arg=foo.DEFAULT)`. If you use it consistently, it could be a fairly clean way to handle it, but still more complex.)

Answer (score 4):

If you know the default, you can use [`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
foo(val1, val2, mydict.get('SomeKey', 'en'))
```

Comment: this is true, but creates a dependency between the default in the function definition and where the function is called.  Nice though

Comment: @wallacer You could try making what `.get()` should return an argument to the function - add an argument like `d`, and have `mydict.get('SomeKey', d)`. You could then override the default if you needed to, but still only define the default in one place.

Answer (score 2):

Can you mess with `foo`?

```
def foo(a,b,c='en',**kwargs):
    ...
```

Then to call it with your dictionary:

```
foo('bar','baz',**mydict)
```

---

an ugly way to do it (that doesn't mess with foo) would be:

```
foo( val1,val2,mydict[ "SomeKey" ]) if "SomeKey" in mydict else foo(val1,val2)
```

Although really, my preferred method -- assuming that `foo` **cannot raise a KeyError** would be: (especially if `'SomeKey'` will be in the dict more often than not):

```
try:
    foo(val1,val2,c=mydict['SomeKey'])
except KeyError:
    foo(val1,val2)
```

This avoids repeated key lookups, and makes it explicit that you're calling a function with a default argument.

---

Or with `inspect` plus `dict.get` as mentioned by phihag:

```
foo(val1,val2,mydict.get('SomeKey',inspect.getargspec(foo).defaults[0]))
```

Note that if you use this one, and `foo` will be inspected repeatedly, you might want to save the result somewhere you can access it.

Comment: definitely +1 here!  Very creative with the introspection :)

Comment: won't your preferred method catch any KeyError within foo?  Meaning if foo calls bar, and bar has a KeyError in it somewhere, we bounce all the way back out, catch the exception, then call foo again with just val1, val2?  Seems like that could be an issue...

Comment: @wallacer -- That's a reasonable point.  I suppose I was assuming that `foo` has no opportunity to raise a `KeyError`.  I'll make that more explicit in my answer